# the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process though streamreader is closed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, file-io

I'm trying to move a file :

```
File.Move(fileFullPath, historyFileFullPath);
```

After i have closed the stream reader :

```
parser.Close();


/// <summary>
/// closes the file stream
/// </summary>
public void Close()
{
   streamReader.Close();
}
```

Yet i'm getting the error :
the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
can anybody shed some light ?

Comment: try disposing streamReader..

Comment: Leverage the `using` statement when working with `IDisposable` objects like `StreamReader`. They are guaranteed to get disposed properly. Build it, use it, and dispose it. Please, please, please; don't share it.

Comment: could you please elaborate on how to do such thing ?

Comment: Using(streamreader reader = New streamreader(...)) { //logic Here }

Answer (score 2):

You can read about the `using` statement [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The most basic example for `StreamReader` is:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
{
    //use sr here without worrying 
}
```

Comment: unfortunately i cannot use it since the streamReader is a private part of a class called CreditFileParser. i understand what you are saying and if it was a new system i would probably do so.

Comment: it closes it - i've tried after reviewing other solutions - also dispose it , and also use - GC.Collect() after closing, yet none of them seems to work

Comment: How could you try to dispose it, if it's in a private part? Is it passed in as a parameter?

Comment: @barakbenhorin I'm asking, because if yes, you could write a wrapper for it (sorry, forgot to tag you in previous comment).

Comment: it's bit complex since the streamreader is used inside a class ( a parsing class ) and to do such changes i would have to change alot of code. my teamleader solved it . i'll upload the answer

Comment: @barakbenhorin All right. But that doesn't matter in the context of my question - if it's passed to this class as a method argument, or a constructor, then a wrapper is the solution.